# Recording membership benefits (specifically vouchers)

Tags: civimember

Our members receive, based on their membership, vouchers for consumption in a restaurant.
They receive these vouchers yearly it can be anything from a voucher for $50, to multiple $50 vouchers and different amounts too (either fixed or completly individual).

Each voucher is assigned to a contact, it has a status (open, spent), has a specific amount, an individual number or other id and a issued-on, valid-from, valid-to- and spent-on-date. A contact can have several vouchers.

The restaurant will collect the vouchers regularly and send them to us for reimbursement (where we'll change the status to spent).

Is there an easy way to manage these vouchers in CiviCRM?

Thank you!

Comment: Another approach to consider would be a custom Activity

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a new custom field set, make sure you select the ‘Does this Custom Field Set allow multiple records?’ option.
Make sure the display style is ‘Tab with table -

[image: Custom Data]

Create the desired custom fields and the data will be displayed as below -

[image: Voucher Custom Data]

Comment: Thank you, I've used that solution and it's working great.

One follow-up question: I'm trying to auto-generate the voucher-id in the format contactId-year-auto_increment_number. Based on the field-editing from, I can create a custom PHP hook for that. However there's not a lot of documentation on that.

I'm assuming I need a hook_civicrm_customPre hook to set the field value based on my "algorithm" ? Where do I register those hooks? (I'm using Civi with wordpress)

Thank you!