# unable to get hook_civicrm_post and _custom to work

Tags: custom-fields, hooks

I'm using CiviCRM 5.57.3 to implement some voucher management functionality [See this question](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/43410/recording-membership-benefits-specifically-vouchers).

I'm now trying to get a hook working, to set my voucher ID in the custom field. I've create a file *civicrmHooks.php* in my "Custom PHP Directory" and tried to simply log something:

```
<?php

// Implements hook_civicrm_pre

add_filter( 'civicrm_post', 'gutschein_id_custom_callback', 10, 4 );

function gutschein_id_custom_callback( $op, $groupID, $entityID, &$params ) {
  // your code here
  Civi::log()->debug(__FUNCTION__);
}

Civi::dispatcher()->addListener('hook_civicrm_post', "myextension_buildForm", $priority);

function myextension_buildForm($event) {
  Civi::log()->debug(__FUNCTION__);
}
?>
```

I've tried registering the hook using both methods described in the documentation [Hooks in Wordpress](https://docs.civicrm.org/dev/en/latest/hooks/usage/wordpress/) [Symfony Event Listener](https://docs.civicrm.org/dev/en/latest/hooks/usage/symfony/#events). Using the *civicrm_custom* hook did not change anything.

However, I'm unable to get anything in the CiviCRM log. Is there anything I'm overseeing?
Thank you!

Comment: I've partially solved this by creating a small extension. That way I can get the hooks to be invoked. I'm now using the _custom hook. And I get the custom field values in $param. However, I don't get the custom_fields unique id in the param list. Which is what I wanted to use in my key...

Comment: Extensions are much preferred - the 'custom php directory' is rarely used now.  If I'm understanding you correctly, the id you want is `$entityID`, not in `$params`

Comment: Thank you, yes I did notice that and I was getting it to work with an extension. However I had to look for another solution, because what I was trying to do seems impossible to do.
Thank you!

Comment: OK - what is it that you're trying to do?

Comment: I was trying to auto-generate the voucher ID with some kind of unique id. I thought that I might be able to access the id field of the custom field, but it was not available in any of the hooks I was trying.